# _Pragma preprocessor operator in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, portability, pragma, c-preprocessor

Is there something like the ANSI C operator `_Pragma` in Visual C++?

For example, I'm trying to define the following macro:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#define PRAGMA_IF_OPENMP(x) _Pragma (#x)
#else  // #ifdef _OPENMP
#define PRAGMA_IF_OPENMP(x)
#endif  // #ifdef _OPENMP
```

So I can circumvent compiler warnings for unknown `#pragma omp ...` in older GCC compilers.
Is there a similar means available in VisualC++?

Comment: I recommend just disabling that warning. OpenMP pragmas are designed to be otherwise harmless in compiler that does not support them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but it's two underscores: `__pragma`

I'm not sure about how the `omp` pragma works, however, here's an example using VC++'s `optimize` pragma:

```
#define PRAGMA_OPTIMIZE_OFF __pragma(optimize("", off))

// These two lines are equivalent
#pragma optimize("", off)
PRAGMA_OPTIMIZE_OFF
```

**EDIT:** I've just confirmed that the `omp` pragmas can also be used like this:

```
#define OMP_PARALLEL_FOR __pragma(omp parallel for)
```

So, yes, your macro should work if defined as follows (note that your original code incorrectly used the stringizing operator `#x`:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#define PRAGMA_IF_OPENMP(x) __pragma (x)
#else  // #ifdef _OPENMP
#define PRAGMA_IF_OPENMP(x)
#endif  // #ifdef _OPENMP
```

Comment: Actually, the GCC documentation gives an example with `#x`.

Comment: @Manuel - I think you're confusing `_Pragma` with `__pragma`; they are unfortunately different entities with different syntaxes (and the latter is MSVC specific). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/c-c-pragma-in-define-macro/3030312#3030312