# Preprocessor token pasting in GCC’s _Pragma operator

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I’m trying to do something similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782049/1968), namely, conditionally include OpenMP pragmas in my program. However, I want to go one step further and avoid that the user needs to specify `omp` every time they use the pragma. In other words, I want the following code to compile:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <omp.h>

#ifdef _OPENMP
#   define LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(x) _Pragma("omp " #x)
#else
#   define LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(x)
#endif

int main() {
    LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(parallel) {
        std::printf("Hello from thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn’t work. The compiler complains:

> error: `_Pragma` takes a parenthesized string literal

If I use the following form, it works, though:

```
#define LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(x) _Pragma(#x)

…

LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(omp parallel) …
```

However, I’d really like to avoid this redundancy. **How can I paste the (stringified) tokens correctly inside the `_Pragma` operator?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much trial and error, it turns out that the simplest solution works:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#   define LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(x)  DO_PRAGMA(omp x)
#   define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma ( #x )
#else
#   define LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(x)
#endif
```

With `-DOPENMP`, I get:

```
# 12 "test_op.cpp"
#pragma omp parallel
# 12 "test_op.cpp"
```

And without it, nothing.

Comment: If it was so obvious, why was it like the 20th thing I tried? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MAKE_STRING(x)  #x
#define LIB_PRAGMA_OMP(x) _Pragma(MAKE_STRING(omp x))
```

Also works, if you prefer that. I like it better because it minimizes the amount of work this helper function does.