# Getting error while using openmp in preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP code in preprocessor directives but I am getting error while compiling the code. 
I am trying to do something like below.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<omp.h>
 #define SUM(_X_)
 sum=0.0                            \
 /*I want to put openmp     
  parallel for directive here       \   
 i.e., #parallel for reduction(+:sum)\
  */                                 \
 for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)          \  
    sum += _X_[i];              \
int main()
{
   int i=0,x[10];
   float sum=0;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      x[i]=i;
   SUM(x);
}
```

Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Put `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)` just before `SUM(x);`

Answer (score 2):

In C, since C99, you have the `_Pragma` operator that allows you to place pragmas inside macros, e.g.

```
#define SUM(_X_)                         \
sum=0.0;                                 \
_Pragma("parallel for reduction(+:sum)") \
for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)               \
    sum += _X_[i]
```

BTW, be careful, never place a terminating `;` at the end of a macro definition.

Comment: Woah! That's an even better answer.  I had to add a `;` after `sum=0.0` and a backslash after `SUM(_X_)` but otherwise ti works.  I wonder if it works in MSVC.  I can't test it now.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with MSVC as well but a little differently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782049/pragma-preprocessor-operator-in-visual-c

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenMP 3.1 standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf), section 2.1,  says that (emphasis mine):

> OpenMP directives for C/C++ are specified with the pragma
>   **preprocessing directive**.

Now, both in C and in C++, you **are not allowed** to introduce new preprocessor macros during the macro expansion phase, and that's why you get an error.

For instance in the latest [C++ standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (section 16) you will find the following:

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not
>   subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated

followed by an example that closely resembles your snippet:

> In:
>
> ```
> #define EMPTY
> EMPTY #include <file.h>
> ```
>
> the sequence of preprocessing tokens on the second line is not a
>   preprocessing directive, because it does not begin with a `#` at the start of translation phase 4, even though it will do so after the macro `EMPTY` has been replaced.

Anyhow, as correctly stated in other answers, you can obtain the same effect as the one you are seeking using the `_Pragma` operator since C99 and C++11. An example from section 16.9 of the same C++ standard draft:

> #pragma listing on "..\listing.dir"
>
> can also be expressed as:
>
> ```
> _Pragma ( "listing on \"..\\listing.dir\"" )
> ```
>
> The latter form is processed in the same way whether it appears
>   literally as shown, or results from macro replacement, as in:
>
> ```
> #define LISTING(x) PRAGMA(listing on #x)
> #define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
> LISTING( ..\listing.dir )
> ```

Finally, pay attention at the *choice of your names*, as `_X_` is potentially a name reserved to the implementation (section 17.6.4.3.2):

> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
>   the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an    underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the  implementation for any use
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the    implementation for use as a name in the global namespace

Comment: Good explanation.  I don't need to read the standard.  I can just read your answers.