# How portable is an if clause on a parallel directive?

Tags: openmp

This is related to [How to disable OMP in a translation unit at the source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972774). The patch I am working on has the following due to benchmarking results. It appears we need the ability to turn off OMP on the translation unit:

```c++
static const bool CRYPTOPP_RW_USE_OMP = true;
...

ModularArithmetic modp(m_p), modq(m_q);

#pragma omp parallel sections if(CRYPTOPP_RW_USE_OMP)
{
    #pragma omp section
        m_pre_2_9p = modp.Exponentiate(2, (9 * m_p - 11)/8);
    #pragma omp section
        m_pre_2_3q = modq.Exponentiate(2, (3 * m_q - 5)/8);
    #pragma omp section
        m_pre_q_p = modp.Exponentiate(m_q, m_p - 2);
}
```

The patch also applies to a cross platform library (Linux, Unix, Solaris, BSDs, OS X and Windows), and it supports a lot of older compilers. I need to ensure that I don't break a compile.

***Question***: how portable is the `#pragma omp parallel sections if(CRYPTOPP_RW_USE_OMP)`? Will using it break compiles that used to work with just `#pragma omp parallel sections`?

I tried looking at [past OpenMP specifications, like 2.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/cspec20.pdf), but I can't see where its allowed in the grammar (see Appendix C). The closest I could find is the *parallel-directive* production (line 22), which leads to *parallel-clause* (line 24) and then *unique-parallel-clause*.

And looking at documentation for platforms I can't test on, its not clear to me if its available. For example, Microsoft's documentation for Visual Studio 2005 appears to only [allow it on a loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5187hzke%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the very document you link, page 8, section 2.2 `parallel` Construct. `if` is among the available clauses (the first one). It is part of the standard, so portable across all conforming compilers.

In your MSDN link:

> if applies to the following directives:
>
> **parallel**
>
> for (OpenMP)
>
> sections (OpenMP)

Comment: Oh, I see. For Microsoft, I went by the description of *"Specifies whether a loop should be executed in parallel or in serial."* I'm on a laptop with limited screen real estate, so I did not scroll down the page. So I'm clear, this will be available in all conforming OMP compilers, regardless of the OMP version. Is that correct?

Comment: The document is for OMPv. 2.0, for older versions you must look into the specifications, I do not remember all historic versions by hearth.

Comment: @jww Also, your MSDN link is obsolete. It is even written there that you should follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5187hzke%28v=vs.140%29.aspx The word *loop* is corrected there.

Comment: Well, its an old link. I landed on the Visual Studio 2013 page of the docs. Then I went back as far as I could using the *Other Versions*. Crypto++ still has VC 5.0 project files, so I can't break the compile going back even earlier than VS 2005.

Comment: The `if` clause is part of the original OpenMP 1.0 specification for C/C++. It **must** be supported by any existing OpenMP-enabled compiler. The same applies to the combined `parallel sections` directive.